# Prove that: If $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{m} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ has a multiplicative inverse, then this is definitely unique

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, proof-explanation

> Prove that: If $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{m} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ for
>   $m \in \mathbb{N}$ has a multiplicative inverse, then this is
>   definitely unique.

I don't know where we can start with this proof but I think it's important to know that $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{m}$ has got a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ if and only if the $\text{gcd }(n,m)=1$. That's what I have learned some days ago here, from many answers.

Maybe it's somehow possible to deduce it from this fact in order to prove it? Because that's what comes to my mind when we talk about multiplicative inverses :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $k,l$ are multiplicative inverses of $n$ then what is 
$$knl=?$$

Comment: Hmm so $k$ is multiplicative inverse of $n$. Then $kn=nk=1$ and because $l$ is an inverse of $k$, we have that $ln=nl=1$ and this fulfills the definition of a multiplicative inverse. $\Rightarrow l=1 \cdot l=(kn)l=k(nl)=k(nl)=k \cdot 1=k$. So $l=k=n^{-1}$ and uniqueness is proven by this?

Comment: @berndgr Yes. You proved that any two inverses are equal, which means uniqueness..

Comment: Awesome, thank you :) Just one question, how much time did you need so that hint came to your mind and you posted it here? Instantly? :P

Comment: @berndgr This is the standard proof that the inverse is unique in Algebra. The same way we prove that the inverse of a matrix or of a bijection is unique.... Or more generally in any ring/group/monoid the inverse of an element is unique.