# Prove that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$, $p$ prime has a multiplicative inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

> $p$ is a prime number. Show that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}
> \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ has a multiplicative inverse.

It might base on my previous question I solved yesterday with help of user *N. S.*: [Prove that: If $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{m} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ has a multiplicative inverse, then this is definitely unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012603/prove-that-if-n-in-mathbbz-m-setminus-left-0-right-has-a-multiplic/2012607?noredirect=1#comment4133450_2012607)

I don't know.. Maybe it would work via induction? It would be nice if it would.

What I thought but not sure if it will work:

Let $m=p$ be prime number and $x \in Z_{p}$ where $Z_{p} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$.

Then $x$ is not divisible by $p$

$\Rightarrow \text{gcd}(x,p)=1$

Thus, there exists a representation $a \cdot x + b \cdot p=1$, where $a,b$ are integers.

Well actually I can stop here because we got $\text{gcd}(x,p)=1$ which already shows there exists a multiplicative inverse, I think?

But this all sounds very strange, maybe there is another way?

Comment: I think your way is fine. You know that $x$ is not divisible by $p$ because otherwise from $ax+bp=1$ would follow $p|1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $(x,y) = 1$ implies that $x$ is invertible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_y$, and it is related to bezout's theorem. In your answer you failed to make the last jump in showing that Bezout's theorem explicitly gives the inverse.

Indeed, since $(x,p) = 1$ we have some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a x + b p = 1$. Taking this equation mod $p$, we have $a x = 1$.

Comment: Oh thank you, knew there was something wrong :P